# Why do hrefs in facebook application tabs get rewritten as anchors?

Tags: facebook, fbml

So I have 2 application tabs added to a profile page in facebook. I am trying to link back and forth between the two tabs. Facebook mysteriously adds them as anchors

http://www.facebook.com/pages/blahblah/12313123231231?v=app_23423423423#!blahblah/12313123231231?v=app_2342332423423

I don't get it. Looking at the source of Dove's site, my only guess is that they do links via javascript:

http://www.facebook.com/dove?v=app_6009294086#!/dove?v=app_127320750626819

Any thoughts?

Steve

Comment: To confirm your suspicions, yes: Facebook re-writes links so that they can be loaded directly by the browser, and also loaded dynamically by the page (AJAX-style). This often involves putting the destination into both a querystring and a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Aaah, facebook. So I anchored the href and added an onclick with document.setLocation('absoluteurl').

Good times FB, good times.